# I need to read XML file using etree in python, I have the below code

Tags: python

Below code is not working if XMLNS tag is present in the xml file. How can I remove XMLNS tag, so that I can read the xml and update the value in xml w.o affecting XML format. If I won't remove XMLNS tag it is corrupting my xml file by adding namespace.

```
import os
import re
import sys
import math
import shutil
import string
import subprocess
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
from optparse import OptionParser
from array import *

with open("file1.txt") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        line = line.strip()
        for number in line.split():
            #int(data[0])
            data=(float(number))

data=int(math.ceil(data))
data=(data*1024*1024)
data=hex(data)[2:]
tree = et.parse("..\FFUPackages\MemoryReservation.pkg.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

#del root.attrib["xmlns"]
#root[0][0][0][0].set("text","tony")
labels = tree.findall("Components/OSComponent/RegKeys/RegKey/RegValue")
#print labels
for label in labels:
    #lineNum = lineNum + 1
    #print label.find("Name")
    if (label.get("Name")=="MemoryReservation"):
        print label.get("Name")
        #print label.set("int", data)
        #self.logger.info("\t>Updating QCLabel.xml")
        label.set("Value", str(data))
root.set("xmlns","urn:Microsoft.WindowsPhone/PackageSchema.v8.00")

tree.write("..\FFUPackages\MemoryReservation.pkg.xml")
```

Comment: You should regex to remove XMLNS I think.

Comment: Please include a sample of the XML.